# How to change structure of URL

Tags: laravel, routes

Currently my URL for my posts is like `domainName\posts\id`.

How do I change this to `domainName\id`?

In my `web.php` I'm using `resource`.

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using custom URLS for your post and get requests like this

```
Route::post('/{any}', 'PostController@postAnything');
Route::get('/{any}', 'PostController@getAnything');
```

Although this will not be a good practice because these are wild cards and will not let pass any of your requests below them.

Comment: Okay. So, is there any better option for this?

Comment: as mentioned on answer, putting any wildcards directly after domain is not a good practice, however if you really need it, put it on your bottom part of web.php

for example if you had routes like this
Route::get('about-us',controller)
Route::get('faq',controller)

--- here route::get('{wildcards}',controller)

Comment: yes you can add any prefix before it. like 

Route::post('posting/{any}', 'PostController@postAnything');

Comment: @JesseJames Also please mention the technology stack in you question.

Comment: To use custom URLs do I have to remove `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');` from `web.php`?

Comment: no just place custom URL above your resource routes